# What is the best IIS tracing tool you have used?

Tags: iis-7

I have spent majority of my career using and troubleshooting IIS Web Server. According to me the best thing happened to a Web admin is FRT (Failed Request Tracing) in IIS 7.0.
I have used Event Tracing for Windows as well and FRT is as much helpful.
Is there any such tracing tool which can give such good in-depth and greater understanding on request flow through the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I use Event Tracing for Windows, if I want to troubleshoot an issue like say "**Users are getting prompted when trying to access Anonymous Authenticated Web site**". ETW gives details on how each ISAPI treated the request or What Authentication happened for every single request a User makes.

In Windows Server 2003, you can use logman to query for build-in providers which you can use to trace. I use the following providers, you are free to add your own for specific tracing:

```
{DD5EF90A-6398-47A4-AD34-4DCECDEF795F} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # HTTP Service Trace                       
{DC1271C2-A0AF-400F-850C-4E42FE16BE1C} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # IIS: IISADMIN Global
{D55D3BC9-CBA9-44DF-827E-132D3A4596C2} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # IIS: WWW Global
{1FBECC45-C060-4E7C-8A0E-0DBD6116181B} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # IIS: SSL Filter
{3B7B0B4B-4B01-44B4-A95E-3C755719AEBF} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # IIS: Request Monitor
{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83} 0xFFFFFFFE 0x5 # IIS: WWW Server
{A1C2040E-8840-4C31-BA11-9871031A19EA} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # IIS: WWW Isapi Extension
{06B94D9A-B15E-456E-A4EF-37C984A2CB4B} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # IIS: Active Server Pages (ASP)
{AFF081FE-0247-4275-9C4E-021F3DC1DA35} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # ASP.NET Events
{e13c0d23-ccbc-4e12-931b-d9cc2eee27e4} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # .NET Common Language Runtime             
{C92CF544-91B3-4dc0-8E11-C580339A0BF8} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # NTLM Security Protocol
{bba3add2-c229-4cdb-ae2b-57eb6966b0c4} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # Active Directory: Kerberos
{f33959b4-dbec-11d2-895b-00c04f79ab69} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # Active Directory: NetLogon
{cc85922f-db41-11d2-9244-006008269001} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # Local Security Authority (LSA)
{8e598056-8993-11d2-819e-0000f875a064} 0xFFFFFFFF 0x5 # Active Directory: SAM
```

Save this text in a file named `iis.guid` and the use couple of batch file to start and stop tracing.

StartTracing.cmd:

```
logman start Iis6.Trace -pf iis.guid -ets -ct perf
```

StopTracing.cmd:

```
logman stop Iis6.Trace -ets
```

You can then use LogParser tool to parse the .etl file.

```
cscript DumpTraceReqs.js c:\EtwTracing\Iis6.Trace.etl > c:\EtwTracing\logfile.txt
```

Now, reading this logfile.txt is easy and gives detailed information.
I have also used

1. Dbgview.exe from http://live.sysinternals.com/ in IIS 5.0.
2. Process Monitor from http://live.sysinternals.com/
3. Failed Request Tracing for tracing in IIS 7 / 7.5

I wonder if there are any more we can use..

Comment: +1 but why is it community wiki?