# IIS - Tracing Web requests/resposes

Tags: iis, iis-6

Being developer; I love Fiddler...

Is there similar tool/utility (preferably free) for server side tracing the web requests and the responses? I would love some utility which is fiddler like, i-e on start up you select particular IIS web site and it start tracing the requests / response (full content) for debugging purposes.

Comment: The apps I want to debug are ASP.NET; some ASP.NET Filter that logs all the requests / responses (raw) and some utility that shows it real time (Fiddler like) would be great!

It would be for occassional purposes; like some ASMX / WCF is hosted and someone is trying to use it from Silverlight / PHP client and getting error...with such tool in place we can debug the issues like request is not well formatted; some required header is not being provided etc

Answer (score 1):

You could look for ETW Tracing.. I really love it [What is the best IIS tracing tool you have used?](https://serverfault.com/questions/121765/what-is-the-best-iis-tracing-tool-you-have-used)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this little (commercial, I think there is a X days trial period) tool in the past: [IIS Tracer](http://iismonitor.motobit.com/). It's a real time IIS monitor. That means you can watch in real-time or log state of each HTTP request, incoming/outgoing bytes, HTTP headers etc.

The tool itself will not win a design price, but it's pretty effective. Also, don't be scared when you see go the website of that product, the pages there are almost plain text.

Answer (score 0):

To track requests the web server is making:
You can just adjust `defaultProxy` settings inside `web.config` and proxy all your requests to Fiddler, either locally on the server or to a remote instance of Fiddler. Refer to [defaultProxy documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx).

To track requests to the web server and their responses:
[Fiddler reverse proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Help/ReverseProxy.asp) is the way to go for debugging.